# Symplectic principal bundles

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, lie-groups, sg.symplectic-geometry, principal-bundles

A symplectic principal bundle is a principal bundle $(X,B, G)$ with projection map $q:X\to B$ such that $X$ and $B$ are symplectic manifolds and the right action of $G$ preserves the symplectic structure of $X$.

1)Does this imply that $G$ admit a symplectic structure?

2)Under what conditions the following map preserves the standard Poisson Lie structures ?

$$ T:C^{\infty} (X) \to C^{\infty} (B)\\ T(f)(b)= \int_{q^{-1}(b)} fd\mu $$

Here $\mu$ is the natural normalized Haar measure of the fibers of $X$.

**Remark:** Considering the  natural principal bundle  structure $q:S^3 \to S^2$, the above  construction provides a Lie  bracket structure  on $C^{\infty}(S^3)$  with $[f,g]=[T(f),T(g)]\circ q$  where  right hand bracket is  the  natural Lie  bracket  on $C^{\infty}(S^2)$. (But  does  it  satisfy the Leibniz rule, hence giving a poisson structure on $S^3$?)

With a modification of the same construction one can give an alternative Lie  bracket structure on $\chi^{\infty}(S^3)$.

Comment: The answer of 1. is yes see section 1.1 of François Lalonde, Dusa McDuff
, Symplectic structures on fiber bundles

http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0040938301000209

Comment: @HassanJolany  Thank you for your very helpful comment and very interesting link.

Comment: $S^2$ is coadjoint orbit, hence it has Kirillov-Kostant-Souriau symplectic structure , and every symplectic manifold has Poisson structure, see http://staff.www.ltu.se/~norbert/home_journal/electronic/93art5.pdf . Also $S^3\cong SU(2)$, you can find in p.13 a Poisson structure on $SU(2)$, http://www.mat.univie.ac.at/~michor/lie-pois.pdf

Comment: @HassanJolany  Thanks for your comment. Regarding the  first of your comment, I think there is  an easier Poison structure  for  $S^2$ since it is  a  symplectic manifold with its  volume form. But I am not sure that this  is equivalent to the poison structure which you explained. I was not aware of such structure, I will read the  linked and  references you provided. But I wonder whether the Lie  bracket on S^3 which I suggested in the question, gives an alternative  poison structure on S^3.

Comment: I think(if I remember correcctly) you may try for such Poisson structure  $\pi=\sum_{i,j,k,l}X_i\frac{\partial}{\partial X_j}\wedge \frac{\partial}{\partial X_k}\wedge \frac{\partial}{\partial X_l}$ where $X_i$ means rotation in direction $X_i$-axis on $S^3$, (I remember the proof of such Poisson structure took 3 lecture of Ctirad Klimcik)

Comment: Is the notion of "Symplectic Principal bundles" a standard one? I could not find anything in google search..